# Turn volume off when locking screen in Windows?

Tags: windows-xp, audio

I'm working as software developer in a rather loud room with lots of distractions, that's why I've got my headphones on most of the time. However, whenever I leave for a meeting or lunch or whatever, I usually forget to turn the music off, so that my colleagues are rather annoyed by the hissing sound from my headphones.

What I thought about was this: turn the volume off on screen lock and back on when unlocked. How does one do that on a Windows XP box?

Comment: wow what a neat idea... +1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [MonitorES](http://code.google.com/p/monitores/). You can find more information about this little app on [Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/5314349/monitores-updates-pauses-any-media-player-when-you-lock-your-pc):

> Tiny, portable utility MonitorES not only turns off the monitor when you lock your PC, it also pauses almost any media player and even sets your Google and Yahoo IM status to away.
>   We've written about this utility before, but since then it has updated with support for nearly any media player, added support for Yahoo Messenger, and you can now use it to simply pause your media with the Pause key. As before, you simply need to launch the utility, set the options, and the next time you lock your workstation your monitor will turn off, and your media will pause.

Comment: nice find indeed! +1

Answer (score 0):

This should work too, save the piece of code under e.g. "mute.vbs". 
When you leave your workplace, double click the file and your Sound is off + your Screen is locked.
After your meeting and the login you'll see a Popup, which can turn the Sound on.

```
On Error Resume Next

set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
un_mute()
oShell.Run "%windir%\System32\rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation"

intAnswer = Msgbox("Do you want to unmute?", vbYesNo, "Volume")
if intAnswer = vbYes then
    un_mute()
end if

sub un_mute()

oShell.run"Sndvol32"
WScript.Sleep 1000
oShell.SendKeys"{TAB 2} "
oShell.SendKeys"%{F4}"

end sub
```

It's not perfect for sure, but works for me.
Also it works for every Player under Windows + no additional Software to install ;-)

Comment: i love QD :) +1