# Is there a freeware utility to pause / unpause WMP upon locking the screen?

Tags: windows, automation, media-player

I've found this: [Automated Pausing/Unpausing](http://www.download3k.com/System-Utilities/Automation-Tools/Download-doPause.html), but I can't find any freeware utility which does the same thing.

Is there one out there that I am missing, or is there a media player which does this out of the box?

Comment: I think this might be a dup: http://superuser.com/questions/32933/turn-volume-off-when-locking-screen-in-windows"

However that accepted answer did not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe an [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script?

Comment: good idea! +1

Comment: Will be looking into this today.